# tSQLt testing between source and destination database

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tsqlt

I have data loaded from Oracle DB to SQL Server every day via SSIS job. I have asked to verify in tSQLt whether a number of records on oracle DB loaded correctly in SQL Server. How can I do this testing in tSQLT on SQL Server?

Comment: I would argue that tSQLt is not the correct tool for this task.  tSQLt is for unit testing SQL Server code.  It's not meant for auditing production data.  You should be writing production queries to do this.

Comment: If you turn on SSIS **verbose** logging, it will log # of rows flowing in the pipelines in the SSIS Data Flows. So, you can use those numbers for comparison/testing.